# Random numbers in Java loops and if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, random, while-loop

I am writing a program where the user enters a number and the computer guesses the number.

I'm having trouble with my `else`/`if` statement inside of my `while` loop. The problem is it prints out `"guess higher"` but the computer does not always guess higher. I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

```
while(computerGuess != userGuess) {
    if(computerGuess > userGuess) {
        System.out.println("Guess lower: ");
        computerGuess = guess.nextInt(userGuess);
        System.out.println(computerGuess);
    }else if(computerGuess < userGuess) {
        System.out.println("Guess higher: ");
        computerGuess = guess.nextInt(101);
        System.out.println(computerGuess);
    }
    amountTries++;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is the `guess` variable a `java.util.Random`?

Comment: If you're using `java.util.Random`, then [take a look at javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-). `nextInt(101)` will return a random number between 0 and 100 - it's **not** guaranteed to be higher than the previous one.

Comment: `guess.nextInt(userGuess)` ... that's a bit unfair for the PC, cause it can never guess the correct number with that line. `guess.nextInt(101)` That needs and offset and is it guaranteed, that the users number is lower than 101?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is it prints out "guess higher" but the computer does not
>   always guess higher. I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

You are specifying a hard-coded limit of 101 for the random number generation. But in the case where the computer guess is smaller than the user value, you need to have a random number generated between the computer guess and the user guess.

**Replace**

`computerGuess = guess.nextInt(101);`

**with**

`computerGuess = guess.nextInt(userGuess - computerGuess) + computerGuess + 1;`

Comment: This was really helpful Thank you. I guess I just was not thinking hard enough on how to use the variables to manipulate the computers guess.

Comment: @MasonMyers. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a program where computer guesses the number by binary search logic then your code is not going to work. Following code will perform binary search kind of logic.

```
int i=0;int j=101;
while(computerGuess != userGuess) {

    if(computerGuess > userGuess) {
        j=computerGuess;
        System.out.println("Guess lower: ");
        computerGuess = guess.nextInt(j);
        System.out.println(computerGuess);
    }else if(computerGuess < userGuess) {
        i=computerGuess;
        System.out.println("Guess higher: ");
        //computerGuess = guess.nextInt(101);
        computerGuess = guess.nextInt(j - i) +i;
        System.out.println(computerGuess);
    }
    amountTries++;
}
```

PS: Not tested for corner cases. Code is just to provide a basic idea.